# Using the same values folder for different (specific) languages in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

My default app language is English so `strings.xml` is located under `res\values`.

My app should also support `Hebrew`, so I put a `Hebrew` copy of `strings.xml` under `res\values-he`.

My problem is that on some devices, Hebrew is defined as "iw" (instead of "he").

Is there a way to save me the trouble of another copy of `strings.xml` under `res\values-iw`, but to have one folder to handle `he`,`iw` and use the default values folder for all the rest?

Comment: Create symbolic link as described in answer for this question: [How to re-use strings in multi-language resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4334241/716075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue and already answered here:
[CyanogenMod: Translate a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074769/cyanogenmod-translate-a-project/8470980#8470980)

So if you want full support on all devices, you have to include both versions.
It's just copy & paste, where's the trouble? :)